# Hierarchical clustering of a time-series

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I am struggling with hierarchical or clustering. I have the following time-series and I want to cluster to based on time. Would transpose function work for this?

```
structure(list(`04:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05:50` = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06:10` = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06:20` = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06:50` = c(0, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 1), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), `07:10` = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 2), `07:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), `07:30` = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `07:40` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `07:50` = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `08:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08:10` = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08:20` = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08:30` = c(2, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08:40` = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08:50` = c(2, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `09:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `09:20` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 2, 0, 0), `09:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `09:50` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:20` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:30` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `11:00` = c(2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `11:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `11:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `11:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `11:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `11:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `12:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0), `12:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `12:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `12:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `12:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `12:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `13:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `13:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `13:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `13:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `13:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `14:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `14:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `14:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `14:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `14:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15:10` = c(0, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15:20` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), `15:30` = c(0, 
    2, 0, 0, 1, 1), `15:40` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), `15:50` = c(0, 
    2, 0, 0, 1, 0), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), `16:10` = c(0, 
    2, 0, 0, 1, 0), `16:20` = c(2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0), `16:30` = c(2, 
    2, 0, 0, 1, 2), `16:40` = c(2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1), `16:50` = c(2, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 1), `17:00` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0), `17:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `17:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `17:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2), `18:10` = c(0, 
    2, 0, 0, 0, 2), `18:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2), `18:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2), `18:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), `18:50` = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2), `19:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `19:10` = c(1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `19:20` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `19:30` = c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0), `19:40` = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `19:50` = c(1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `20:10` = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `20:20` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `20:30` = c(0, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1), `20:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), `20:50` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1), `21:00` = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), `21:10` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1), `21:20` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), `21:30` = c(0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1), `21:40` = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), `21:50` = c(0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1), `22:00` = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), `22:10` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:20` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:50` = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `23:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `23:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `23:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `23:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `23:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:10` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:50` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

I managed to run hierarchical clustering but only on cases and not on time

```
d_distance <- dist(as.matrix(df))    
plot(hclust(d_distance))
```

The plot that I generated

[image]

As you can see on the plot the structure end points are indexes - how can I have instead of index time (maybe transpose)? Also I would like to plot time-series cluster separately like below plot. Would dtw be better than hierarchical clustering?

[image]

Comment: Is it the case that you have 6 time series and something line 100 observations per time series? If the answer is yes, then you could either use `t` in base R to transpose the data.frame into a matrix after extracting the variable names and then use these as column names in your matrix. Something like `myMat <- t(dat); rownames(myMat) <- names(dat)`  then you will have a matrix where each column is its own time series. However, you might first take a look at what formats time series clustering packages want. I've used `dtwclust` in the past and highly recommend it, there is also `tsclust`.

Comment: @lmo yes I have 6 time series wirh more ghan16000 obs. thanks